# Firestore query is not running with startAfter

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have following firestore query and startAfter is not working there. Instead of "starting after" it restarts at the beginning. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
            const messages = [],
                f = Firebase.firestore()
                    .collection("chat")
                    .doc(chatId)
                    .withConverter(ChatMessageConverter)
                    .collection("messages")
                    .orderBy('creation_time', 'desc')
                    .limit(limit);
            if (!_.isNull(lastActiveDoc))
                f.startAfter(lastActiveDoc);
            const snapshot = await f.get();
```

Comment: "is not working" is hard to help with. What does the code do, and what did you expect it to do? It's often easiest to help if you made the code log a value, put that updated code and its output in the question, and then tell us what you expected it to log instead.

Comment: Query gets docs from beginning, not from given lastActiveDoc.

Comment: Ah, I see. When you call `startAfter(lastActiveDoc)` it returns a new query, so you have to make sure to call `get` on that new query. The simplest way to do that is with `f = f.startAfter(lastActiveDoc);` (so with an additional `f = ` in there, so that you're using the new query.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `startAfter(lastActiveDoc)` (or any other of the query building method) it **returns a new query**. You have to make sure to call get on that new query.

The simplest way to do that is with f = f.startAfter(lastActiveDoc); (so with an additional f =  in there, so that you're using the new query.

So:

```
f = Firebase.firestore()
    .collection("chat")
    .doc(chatId)
    .withConverter(ChatMessageConverter)
    .collection("messages")
    .orderBy('creation_time', 'desc')
    .limit(limit);

if (!_.isNull(lastActiveDoc))
    f = f.startAfter(lastActiveDoc); // the change is in this line

const snapshot = await f.get();
```